# Is resident textures possible in OpenGL ES 1.1?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-to-opengles

Is resident textures possible in OpenGL ES 1.1 like we have in OpenGL?

Answer (score 0):

No; none of the texture memory functions (e.g., `glAreTexturesResident`, `glPrioritizeTextures`, etc.) were included in any version OpenGL ES.